# How to break line with TypeScript

Tags: html, angular, typescript, line-breaks

I am new to angular and I am trying to do a  random quote generator. I got inspired from a tutorial and everything is fine until now but I want to add a line break between the quote and the author.

**What I have:**

> Don't Let Yesterday Take Up Too Much Of Today. - Will Rogers

**What I want:**

> Don't Let Yesterday Take Up Too Much Of Today.
>
> Will Rogers

I have this code so far in my app.component.ts:

```
quotes = [
'The Pessimist Sees Difficulty In Every Opportunity. The Optimist Sees The Opportunity In Every Opportunity',
"Don\'t Let Yesterday Take Up Too Much Of Today. -Will Rogers",
'You Learn More From Failure Than From Success. Don\'t Let It Stop You'
]
 getNewQuote() {
    const quoteText = document.querySelector('.quote-text');
    this.randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.quotes.length));
    quoteText.textContent = this.quotes[this.randomNumber];
    quoteText.textContent = this.quotes[this.randomNumber].split("-");
  }
```

I tried

```
quoteText.textContent = this.quotes[this.randomNumber].split("-");
```

But is is just giving me:

> Don't Let Yesterday Take Up Too Much Of Today. , Will Rogers

I looked for line break with typescript but none of what I did is working. How can i do it?

Comment: What matters is where this text ends up.  I think it will end up in HTML, in which case you should replace "-" or whatever with "<br>".  At least that's one way.

Comment: @user2740650 I tried that already but it is not working

Comment: I just realized you were setting `textContent` explicitly.  That won't interpret HTML.  You could set `innerHTML` instead, and use the `<br>` as I said.  However, I suspect you're not using Angular the way it was intended.  You should not generally manipulate DOM elements directly.

Comment: @user2740650 yesss thank you so much! I put innerHTML and it is working!  Yes I am using angular but it is true that i did not pay attention to indentation since it did not give me any error.

Comment: Do you get your quotes as a string from somewhere or do you set them up yourself?

Comment: Note that using `document.querySelector('.quote-text')` is a very big code-smell in an angular component. You want to use angular features like interpolation instead.

Comment: @RobMonhemius For the quotes yeah I set them up myself at least for the moment. Thank you! I will check other features as you said.

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting up the quotes yourself, you can separate the author from the quote from the start.

I won't recommend using a `regexp` or `split()` to chunk a string in pieces unless you know very precisely where to split your string and that it never fails or splits at the wrong place.

**example**

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ogfspj?file=src/app/app.component.ts

*app.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

interface Quote {
  quote: string;
  author: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public quote: Quote;
  private quotes: Quote[];

  ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.quotes = [
      {
        quote: 'The Pessimist Sees Difficulty In Every Opportunity. The Optimist Sees The Opportunity In Every Opportunity',
        author: 'unknown'
      }, {
        quote: 'Don\'t Let Yesterday Take Up Too Much Of Today', 
        author: 'Will Rogers'
      }, {
        quote: 'You Learn More From Failure Than From Success. Don\'t Let It Stop You',
        author: 'unknown'
      }
    ]

    this.random_quote()
  }

  private random_quote(): void {
    const index = Math.floor( Math.random() * this.quotes.length );
    this.quote = this.quotes[index];
  }

}
```

*app.component.html*

```
<blockquote>
  <i>{{quote.quote}}</i><br><br>
  - {{quote.author}}
</blockquote>
```

**takeaways for beginners**

The big takeaways for beginners from this example would be:

- use an interface to define a `Quote` type, this will be easier to work with
- bind a property using `{{}}`
- most of the time you want to initialise data in the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook; You will probably refactor this code at some point to get the quotes from a service. Then you need to initialise `quote` in this hook.

Answer (score 0):

You are using TypeScript to generate the contents of an HTML page. Hence, your ultimate output is supposed to be HTML code. To break lines in HTML, use the `<br>` tag.

The output generated by your TypeScript code should be something like this:

```
<p>First Line.<br>Second Line</p>
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) is some reference.

Comment: Ok, now I get it, you are using .textContent. Please could you try using .innerHTML ? It should work with that.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by just adding \n at the point where you want to break the quote.

```js
//By adding \n in the text you can Break the line. Happy Coding!
var test = "Hello\nWorld";
console.log(test);
```