# Line break in a template method?

Tags: angular, typescript

How to do a line break in TypeScript ? By searching [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63770808/how-to-break-line-with-typescript) I don't find a solution.

Actually, I have a method that displays 10 numbers, I want to put a line break on each figure.

I have tried with `\n` but doesn't work...

TS

```
export class AppComponent {

  constructor() {}

  public figure(): string {
    let txt = '';
    for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
      txt = txt + i + ' \n ';
    }
    return txt;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<h1>Exercice 9 </h1>
<p> {{ figure() }} </p>
```

Comment: Which library are you using here? Angular, React, Vue, something else?

Comment: @Jeff Bowman: I am in Angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print it in browsers console then `\n` should be enough. If you would like to present it in HTML then I would suggest storing numbers in an array and display it with looping through an array with Angular built in directive `*ngFor`:

```js
public figure(): string {
  let txt = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    txt.push(i);
  }
  return txt;
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let nr of figure()">
  {{nr}}
</div>
```

Additionally you should store `figure` result in a variable to avoid redundant calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here isn't typescript, it's the fact you're rendering the result in HTML. For HTML to display a linebreak you'd need a `<br/>`:

```
public figure(): string {
  let txt = '';
  for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    txt = txt + i + '<br/>';
  }
  return txt;
}
```

Comment: The resultat isn't good -> Here is my display `1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/>5<br/>6<br/>7<br/>8<br/>9<br/>10<br/>`